# retrofit2 POST json to Url contain "/" and "&" "?"

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want post json to a url,this url like: http://service.me.com/index.php?r=login/check&DEBUG=0&M=a;

i write 
`Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://service.me.com/") .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) .build();
......
@POST("index.php?r=login/check&DEBUG=0&M=a")
Call<ResponseBean> getLogin(@Body SendBean body);`

how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
  @POST("index.php")
  Call<ResponseBean> getLogin(@Body SendBean body,
                        @Query("r") String r,
                        @Query("DEBUG") int DEBUG,
                        @Query("M") String M);
```

Comment: Instead of sending this in query "login/check", send it like this "login%2Fcheck". It is encoded.